# Restoring connection to Bluetooth LE server (BluetoothGatt.connect() does not appear to work)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to keep connection between Bluetooth Server and Client alive all the time. It was all right with classic BT connection, however with BT LE the connection is lost when the server goes to sleep. Even though the server Gatt is recovered after getting awake, the client doesn't seem to reconnect and gatt.reconnect() doesn't help to restore the connection.

For simplicity take sample Android apps for the server:

https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver

and for the client:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

This is the relevant part from client code with additional logs for clarification:

```
  public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Re-using existing mBluetoothGatt succeeded.");
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Re-using existing mBluetoothGatt FAILED.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }
```

It can be noticed that device.connectGatt is called with autoconnect=false. Indeed, if I change it to true the connection always fails.

Also it can be seen, that if the Gatt is already set up and device matches the Gatt's device, instead of creating the new connection, the app will always try to re-use existing Gatt with reconnect(), which may succeed or fail, but even if fails, the new connection isn't attempted.

Now start server and client. After the connection is established, press DISCONNECT in to right client's corner to break the connection:

[image]

When I press CONNECT, the re-connection never takes place and I get following log messages:

```
Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.
Re-using existing mBluetoothGatt succeeded.
onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=6 device=40:4E:36:42:DC:35
Disconnected from GATT server.
```

From this we can see that gatt.connect() returns true, however the connection isn't re-established.

Connection restored all right, if I completely remove the code related to reconnection, so the new Gatt is always used. This suggests that the server end is working OK. Still I prefer to-reuse the existing connection, since re-establishing connection all the time may create issues in the real code.